# Disable form animation when created from callback

Tags: eureka-forms

I'm creating a form based on the response from an API call, so the form is created in the completion block of the API request.

Doing this causes the form to "bounce in". If I refresh the API call to get new values and rebuild the form, it "bounces out" then "bounces" back in.

[Example GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4ksV.gif)

Is there any way to disable this bouncing animation?

Answer (score 1):

Use form = Section() instead of form +++ Section

```
class ViewController: FormViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    form = Section("Section1")
        <<< TextRow() { row in
            row.title = "Text Row"
            row.placeholder = "Enter text here"
        }
        <<< PhoneRow() {
            $0.title = "Phone Row"
            $0.placeholder = "Add numbers here"
        }
    +++ Section("Section2")
        <<< DateRow() {
            $0.title = "Date Row"
            $0.value = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)
        }
}
```

[source: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/575](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/575)